# Implementing T::ten()

Tags: generics, rust

I want to implement a function that returns a vector of digits for a given number. For example,

```
digits(1234) -> Vec[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In order to make this function work with any integer type, I wrote the function signature like this:

```
fn digits<T: Num>(T: n) -> Vec<i32> {
   ...
}
```

The basic idea is to get a last digit by `n % 10` in a following loop:

```
let mut acc: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
while n != 0 {
  acc.push(n & 10);
  n /= 10;
}
acc.reverse();
acc // return digits
```

But this works for a specific integer type. I want to make it generic. The problem is that I need a generic `10` as similar to `T::one()`.

I tried multiplying 10 to `T::one()` but didn't work. One other trick I can think of is to add `T::one()` ten times:

```
let ten = T::one() + T::one() + ... + T::one(); // add 10 times
```

But I am not sure this is the best way to do this? Any ideas?

Comment: The `Num` trait (which you should link to in your question) has a method `from_str_radix`, so you _could_ always use `from_str_radix("10", 10)`. If you can spare another trait bound, most types that are `Num` are probably also `From<u8>`.

Comment: Thanks, `match T::from_str_radix("10", 10)` seems like work. The only small problem is that I couldn't use `unwrap()`. I think you can post an answer with more explanation about the later part of your comment.

Comment: I'm not sure that `T::from_str_radix("10", 10)` will be optimized by the compiler. A better way is to add the `T: From<u8>` bound, and use `let ten: T = 10u8.into()`.

Comment: `From<u8>` doesn't work with `i8`, since `u8` could be `255`, but that's outside of `i8`'s range. Honestly the `T::one() + T::one() + ...` approach seems to be the only one that actually covers all the cases, though I can't say it feels very satisfying. Another option is to create a `Ten` trait (which is basically an equivalent to the `One` trait) and manually implement it for all primitive ints, probably with a `macro_rules` macro?

Comment: What I want is to create a `ten` of type `T`. So the source type wouldn't be a matter whether it was `u8` or `i8`. Once I have `ten` of type `T`, the range will be defined by `T`. Am I wrong? One cool thing is that `let ten: T =10u8.into()` doesn't need pattern matching like `from_str_radix(...)`.

Comment: For the record, since you're already using `Num`, [`FromPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/traits/trait.FromPrimitive.html) is likely better, since `i8` doesn't implement `From<u8>`.

Comment: The point about `From<u8>` is that if you have it as the bound on `T`, you won't be able to call `digits(1i8)`, because the bound: `i8: From<u8>` is not satisfied. Admittedly you probably also use `TryFrom<u8>` and unwrap the result

Comment: Seems like `FromPrimitive` works. Why don't you add it as an answer, so other people can see the solution more clearly?

Comment: Sounds like a combination of the two approaches is in order: a `Ten` trait and a blanket implementation for all `One` that does the `T::one() + T::one() + ...` thing. Then, at least in your `digits` function, it's a nice `T::ten()` call, and all of the messiness hides behind another trait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Aplet123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5923139/aplet123) mentioned in the comment above, you can use [`FromPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/traits/trait.FromPrimitive.html).

```
let ten: T = T::from_i8(10).unwrap();
```

I think `unwrap()` is safe as we know that it won't fail.